# Where is the header file of emscripten/bind.h?

Tags: c, debian, emscripten, include-path

I am using emcc to compile c++ to wasm on Debian 11.
It is successfully done.
So I think emcc knows the path.

But VS Code shows error squiggle under `#include <emscripten/bind.h>` because it doesn't know the path to the header file.

Where is the header file?

I'm not familiar to c++ and I install emsdk via git (I just follow the official tutorial here https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/downloads.html).

Comment: what operating system are you using ?

Comment: I'm using linux (in vscode devcontainer. host os is windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found at `./emsdk/upstream/emscripten/bind.h`

https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/main/system/include/emscripten/bind.h